# Android In app walkthrough

Tags: android

How to create in-app step by step instructions?
[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROF16.png) ([first boot android ics](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9ZZQrm07s4A&feature=player_detailpage#t=222s), new google play app etc)

Is it a part of public android sdk?

Comment: The text of the question isn't great, but the links explain perfectly well what is being asked. Its definitely a valuable question, that I haven't seen answered elsewhere. The supposed answer currently marked is a non-answer, and gives no direction help whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone had to program all of that. I'm not sure what else to say, you need to do two things:

1. Sequence through all of the actions you want to perform, and programatically do the things that the button presses do. (Show other screens, launch other activities, etc.)
2. Draw the shapes representing the finger/hand etc.